# Python: Transform pandas dataframe so that index and column ids become elements of a row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm finding this hard to word, but basically I want to reorganise a dataframe such that the index and column ids are elements of the dataframe. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# set seed
np.random.seed(420)
# make example dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(1, 9, size=(4,4)), 
    index=['a','b','c','d'], columns=['a','b','c','d'])

In [1]: df1
Out[1]: 
   a  b  c  d
a  2  1  7  8
b  8  4  7  2
c  3  3  1  7
d  8  7  7  5
```

And I want to reorganise the dataframe to look like this.

```
   id1  id2  value  
 1  a    a    2
 2  a    b    1
 3  a    c    7
 4  a    d    8
 5  b    a    8
 6  b    b    4
 7  b    c    7
 8  b    d    2
 9  c    a    3
10  c    b    3
11  c    c    1
12  c    d    7
13  d    a    8
14  d    b    7
15  d    c    7
16  d    d    5
```

Please feel free to edit the title of my question so it better reflects what I am asking. As I said I found it hard to word what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @sai, I'll mark as a duplicate shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['id1','id2','value']
print (df1)
   id1 id2  value
0    a   a      2
1    a   b      1
2    a   c      7
3    a   d      8
4    b   a      8
5    b   b      4
6    b   c      7
7    b   d      2
8    c   a      3
9    c   b      3
10   c   c      1
11   c   d      7
12   d   a      8
13   d   b      7
14   d   c      7
15   d   d      5
```

Numpy solution with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
a = np.repeat(df.index, len(df.columns))
b = np.tile(df.columns, len(df))
c = df.values.ravel()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id1':a,'id2':b,'value':c})
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much. By the way, I feel I haven't worded this question very well. How would you describe this kind of reorganisation of data and do you know if this question is a duplicate?

Comment: @Lachlan.00 - yes, hard this kind of question is find, but I see there is dupe already found.